# How to hide Sticky header when page load. or Page refresh?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am using a plugin named sticky header. in a word press website for creating sticky header. When I am reloading page or opening my website. sticky header is visible at the time of page reloading and refresh.

Please help me how can I hide or load fist that div...

Answer (score 0):

Set style to 'none' preferably on load:

`document.getElementById('myDivId').style.display = 'none';`

or if you use jQuery:

`$("#myDivId").hide();`

Comment: Its not working..Please have a look http://propdiscuss.com/ without logon its perfectly fine after login it it showing at load time for 2 sec...  http://propdiscuss.com/ user- nitish, password -pass.. Please help